# How to store big data in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am very new to javascript and chrome-extension, I try to create extension that block a few domain. I want to store these domains in a file, maybe the same way adblock do it.

I know there is `localstorage` but is it the only way to store data ?

If stored in a file how can I open it from javascript extension ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

For large data it's recommended to use [Indexed DB](https://devdocs.io/dom/indexeddb_api).

You *can* ask for permission to use large amount of data with  `chrome.storage.local` (and Indexed DB) using the [`unlimitedStorage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) permission (in addition to the regular `storage` permission).

Comment: Note, same permission applies to IndexedDB. Also, only `chrome.storage.local` is unlimited with that permission.

Comment: I've just stored 100MB of data in extension's IndexedDB with no unlimitedStorage permission and no errors were displayed. The data was actually stored and survived restarting the browser. Chrome 60, 62. I wonder if this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be limited in size for safety reason, adblock (to my knowledge) uses external database (public if I'm not mistaking) so you could do the same, like using a google doc shared publicly.
According to this : [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values) the max size is 10Mb

Hope that can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use chrome.storage.local in the chrome storage api: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage